# The surface area of a sphere is..m

Tags: area

The surface area of a sphere is $102\ \mathrm{cm}^{2}$. If the sphere is cut into two hemispheres, what will be the change in surface area ?.

My attempt;

$$
\mbox{Surface area of sphere}\ = 102\,,\quad4\pi r^2=102\,,\quad r=2.8484\ \mathrm{cm}
$$

If the sphere is cut into two hemispheres l,

Surface area of hemisphere $=2\pi r^{2} = 50.9984\ \mathrm{cm}^{2}$.

I have calculated till here. But I did not understand what the question is asking ?.

Comment: Note that both "new" surfaces have "bases" with surface area equal to $\pi r^2$.

Comment: @Dr. MV, what would be my answer, then?

Comment: $4\pi r^2 +\pi r^2+\pi r^2=6\pi r^2=\frac32 \times \,\,\text{surface area of the sphere}$

Comment: How's that? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Cut an apple in matching halves.  Can you see that there is a "flat" part on each half?

Comment: Yes.  I can see that.

Comment: What is the surface area of the flat part of one of the halves?

Comment: Is it $\pi r^2$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  And you have two halves.  The original part of the surface is still there (so that is $4\pi r^2$) and by cutting, we introduce two new portions of surface area each with $\pi r^2$.  The total is then $6\pi r^2$.

Comment: Could you please show the answers in numbers?

Comment: I've posted the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon cutting the sphere into hemispheres, each hemisphere has original surface area $2\pi r^2$ plus the new "flat" part with surface area $\pi r^2$.

Thus, the new total surface area $S_{new}$, is, therefore, $S_{new}=6\pi r^2 =\frac32 \times \,\,\text{Surface Area of the Sphere}=153\,\,\text{cm}^2$.  The change in surface area is thus $51\,\,\text{cm}^2$.